# Why does my application print debug messages after deployment?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I recently deployed my project to the Google App Engine (GAE) as I noticed that all debug messages can be seen in the dev-tool.

I thought that the compiler would remove the debug output as it compiles for release.

This is my current logging configuration in **module.gwt.xml**

```xml
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>   

<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="ALL"/>  
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>       
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="DISABLED"/>
<set-property name="compiler.stackMode" value="emulated"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordLineNumbers" value="true"/>
<set-configuration-property name="compiler.emulatedStack.recordFileNames" value="true"/>
```

How can I get rid of the debug output on my deployed application?

---

I am using [`GWT 2.8.0-beta1`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.8.0-beta1) and this is how I log:

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class MyWidget extends Composite {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyWidget.class.getName());

    // ..

    public void myfunc() {      
        LOGGER.fine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the version of GWT you're using, as well as an example of a debug statement from your app?

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy Yes, of course. See updated question.

Comment: First of all, your last gwt.logging.level is set to FINEST which means all levels above it will be logged (FINE is above FINEST). Try setting log level to INFO for production.

Comment: Secondly, your last gwt.logging.level overrides your first. Leave one, set to INFO.

Comment: Finally, the only log statements I know of being actually compiled out are GWT.log() statements. I'm not sure about logging framework statements.

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy But I want the compiler to remove *all* logging. If I am not mistaken this [should happen](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Making_All_Logging_Code_Compile_Out) if I compile for release. Using `java.util.logging` is the way to go according to the article.

Comment: That will happen if you disable all logging, I.e. set gwt.logging.enabled to FALSE.

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy Hm.. is there a better option something like a compiler flag? I don't want to think about setting it to `FALSE` every time I deploy my application .. There must be a switch to disable that.

Comment: Introduce two modules, module-dev.gwt.xml and module-prod.gwt.xml. In the prod module, disable logging for production.

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy And how does the compiler know which one of those it should use?

Comment: It doesn't until you tell it to as a parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113222/discussion-between-displayname-and-boris-brudnoy).